# CRM Analytics - Application Create Fails

Tags: analytics, crm

We have created a CRM Analytics application that we plan to distribute in a managed package.   Our project includes one waveTemplate.  The template includes data_sets and a recipe that uses data from two standard objects (Account, User) and three objects that are part of our core managed package.

We package it as an embedded app.

We see a synchronization problem when (1) in our development scratch orgs, we execute an sf cli command to create the application using the template  and (2) when we install our analytics package.

1. More on the error we see in scratch orgs.

We run sf analytics app create...  to create the app from the template id.  On the first attempt the create request fails after the first step (Dataset Created) as shown here...

sf analytics app create -t 0Nk8B000000Cc9ZSAS -n Revenova_Analytics -u test-rfq4halqjhj5@example.com
=== Successfully started the creation process for Analytics app [00l8B000000e1TKQAY].
✔ 1 Datasets created, 0 failed
✖ App create Failed with message [Creating application [Revenova_Analytics] failed.]!
ERROR running analytics:app:create:  App create Failed with message [Creating application [Revenova_Analytics] failed.]!

If we run the same command again, it succeeds as shown here...

sf analytics app create -t 0Nk8B000000Cc9ZSAS -n Revenova_Analytics -u test-rfq4halqjhj5@example.com
=== Successfully started the creation process for Analytics app [00l8B000000e1TUQAY].
✔ 1 Datasets created, 0 failed
✔ 1 Recipes created, 0 failed
✔ 1 Images created, 0 failed
✔ 4 Dashboards created, 0 failed
✔ App [Revenova_Analytics] Complete!

After running the two commands, if we log into the org, we see 2 instances of the application in Analytics studio.  One that failed and one that succeeded.  The older one, from the failed attempt has no dashboards, components, lenses, datasets,..  the newer one, from the successful attempt does have dashboards and datasets (which is expected).  The app log shows these messages:
App Log:
Successfully created folder [Revenova_Analytics] with id [00l8K000000e1zFQAQ]
Successfully created dataset [Revenova_Analytics_Dataset].
DataflowInstance [03C8K000000ZVHt] succeeded with status [SUCCESS] for dataflowRequest [0308K000000YaRRQA0]
Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8K000000GpSm] completed with status [FailedStatus].
Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8K000000GpSm] completed with status [FailedStatus].
Didn't start Local DataSync's Dataflow [The dataflow job can’t start because it's already running.]
Didn't start Local DataSync's Dataflow [The dataflow job can’t start because it's already running.]
Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8K000000GpSm] completed with status [FailedStatus].
Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8K000000GpSm] completed with status [FailedStatus].
Didn't start Local data-sync, as it is already pendingApp [Revenova_Analytics], dataset [Base: rtms__Stop__c], dataflow replication id [02K8K000000KEm1UAG]]
Creating application [Revenova_Analytics] failed.

2. Regarding the Package install, we see something similar.  The package installs without showing errors.  But when we login, we don't see the application in Analytics Studio.  In setup, we see errors occurred in the install.
   App construction failures. Below is the application log:

   - Successfully created folder [Revenova_Analytics] with id [00l8N000000qTcKQAU]
   - Successfully created dataset [Revenova_Analytics_Dataset].
   - DataflowInstance [03C8N000000Sem6] succeeded with status [SUCCESS] for dataflowRequest [0308N000000SCY7QAO]
   - Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8N000000Ceop] completed with status [FailedStatus].
   - Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8N000000Ceop] completed with status [FailedStatus].
   - Didn't start Local DataSync's Dataflow [The dataflow job can’t start because it's already running.]
   - Didn't start Local DataSync's Dataflow [The dataflow job can’t start because it's already running.]
   - Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8N000000Ceop] completed with status [FailedStatus].
   - Canceling task because runtime request [0ok8N000000Ceop] completed with status [FailedStatus].
   - Didn't start Local data-sync, as it is already pendingApp [Revenova_Analytics], dataset [Base: rtms__Stop__c], dataflow replication id [02K8N000000QhAvUAK]]
   - Creating application [Revenova_Analytics] failed.

The error output for the embedded app install with the managed package is similar to the app create step on our development scratch orgs.

This appears to be some sort of synchronization error.  It seems processes are colliding with each other.   What is causing this issue?

Thanks